# Adding an element dynamicaly to a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to create a new list element every time a key press is detected. Originally I had this written down--

```
<ul class='text-box'> <strong>THIS IS SPARTA</strong>
 </ul>
  <script>
    keycheck = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function()
    { 
        $('.text-box').text('Number of keypress are: '+keycheck);
        keycheck=keycheck+1;
        $('<p>').text(keycheck).appendTo('.text-box');
    });

    </script>
```

but this only created TWO line on keypress that updated with the number of clicks.
BUT removing the line **"$('.text-box').text('hello '+keycheck);"** gives me what I want.
I would like like to know why it did that, since I just started learning js I feel this would be something valuable.

Comment: you can use .append instead of .text $('.text-box').append('Number of keypress are: '+keycheck);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
$('.text-box').text('Number of keypress are: '+keycheck);
```

you replace all of the contents of `.text-box` with the given text. And "all of the contents" include the content that was added last time!
So you need `append(...)` instead of `text(...)`. That's it.

However, if you want to make a list, you should use list items (`<li>`), not plain text and `<p>`. A better solution looks like this:

```js
 keycheck = 0;
 $(document).keydown(function() {
   $('.text-box').append('<li>Number of keypresses are: ' + keycheck + '</li>');
   keycheck = keycheck + 1;
   $('<li>').text(keycheck).appendTo('.text-box');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='text-box'>
  <li>THIS IS SPARTA</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense!